# Difference between Union Types with Null and Nullable Object declaration in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nullable

I recently found a bit of typescript code in a bigger angular project, that had a Bitwise-OR/Pipe-Symbol within its object declaration.
Like this:

```
dataSource: FileSource | null;
```

In my understanding it is an object of the type *FileSource* that is also *nullable*.

```
dataSource = null; // Works
dataSource = new FileSource... // Works
dataSource = 32; // Error
```

I also found out that you can declare an object with a *whole set of Datatypes* like this:

```
myVariable: number | string | null;
```

Now to my actual question:
I can as well declare an object with a *question mark* as a symbol for nullable.
Is there any difference between these two declarations?

```
myVariable: FileSource | null;
mySecondVariable?: FileSource;
```

If there is no difference between these two, would you consider it a bad practice, as it is not common in other languages and no valid javascript code?

**BTW:** In Javascript this:

```
myVariable: Number | null;
myVariable = "Hello World";
```

would be fine.

My focus is the nullability of an object and how these declarations differ

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any difference between these two declarations?

Yes, particularly [with strict null checks](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#optional-parameters-and-properties). A property with a [union type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (the `|` symbol) is required to be present with a value that matches one of the types.

An [optional property](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties) (declared with `?`) is just that: Optional. The object isn't required to have it at all. Although that said, at the moment (at least), TypeScript treats `prop?: X` exactly like `prop: X | undefined`; see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) helpfully pointed out by [jcatz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz).

*Without* strict null checks, this is fine:

```
type A = {
    dataSource: Date | null
};
type B = {
    dataSource?: Date
};

const a: A = { dataSource: null }; // Works
const b: B = { dataSource: null }; // Also works
```

**With** strict null checks, the second is wrong:

```
type A = {
    dataSource: Date | null
};
type B = {
    dataSource?: Date
};

const a: A = { dataSource: null }; // Works
const b: B = { dataSource: null }; // Error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Date | undefined'.
```

[Live Example in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Go%20to%20the%20options%20and%20enable%20strict%20null%20checks%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20dataSource%3A%20Date%20%7C%20null%0A%7D%3B%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20dataSource%3F%3A%20Date%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20dataSource%3A%20null%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20b%3A%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20dataSource%3A%20null%20%7D%3B)

Similarly, assigning `undefined` would be fine without strict null checks, but with them, it's an error in the union type case:

```
type A = {
    dataSource: Date | null
};
type B = {
    dataSource?: Date
};

const a: A = { dataSource: undefined }; // Error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date | null'.
const b: B = { dataSource: undefined }; // Works
```

[Live Example in the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Go%20to%20the%20options%20and%20enable%20strict%20null%20checks%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20dataSource%3A%20Date%20%7C%20null%0A%7D%3B%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20dataSource%3F%3A%20Date%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%20dataSource%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%3A%20Type%20'undefined'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'Date%20%7C%20null'.%0Aconst%20b%3A%20B%20%3D%20%7B%20dataSource%3A%20undefined%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Works)

Comment: I understand this aspect, but in my specific case with null as a second type, how would it differ?

Comment: There isn't *much* of a difference in TypeScript between a missing property and a property of value `undefined`, and the differences that are there aren't incredibly useful.  [Relevant issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195)

Comment: @jcalz - Briefly there was a copy-and-paste issue with one of them. :-) I fixed them, but you got here at just the wrong moment. Oh, wait, but the same copy-and-paste issue is also elsewhere. Drat. Fixed.

Comment: @Babofett - The third link addresses that; I've updated to add an example and a bit of text around it as well: With strict null checks, assigning `null` would be an error in the optional property case, and assigning `undefined` would be an error in the union type case.

Comment: @jcalz - So there' hope. :-)

Comment: One more point.  If you have `| null` and all strict checks on then the property must be initialized in the constructor or at declaration (because otherwise it would be `undefined` which is not valid).  If you have `| undefined` or `?` then it does not need to be initialized at construction.  Finally you can have `field!: number | null` which can be null but you are asserting it won't be (with the non-null assertion operator `!`) so it doesn't need to be initialized at construction.

Answer (score 6):

There is a big difference. The `?` modifier is actually equivalent to `| undefined`.

These are entirely equivalent:

```
myVariable: FileSource | undefined;
mySecondVariable?: FileSource;
```

Comment: Almost. If you use `myVariable: FileSource | undefined;` you need to pass undefined or FileSource, if you use `mySecondVariable?: FileSource;` you can omit the value